# Access controller from action helper

Tags: zend-framework, helper

Is it possible to access controller from action helper?

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_UserLimit extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public test()
    {
        $this->getController(); // get controller which initiated the helper
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
$controller = $this->getActionController();
```